# Stop Callback Loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, callback, settimeout

Below is a simplified version of my code.

I'm triggering the `loop` function repeatedly by using the callback `loop();`. That's great, but at some point in the future I want to be able to use my `loopStart` function to also stop the `loop();` callback (and thus stop the repeated call of the function). How can I do that?

```
(function loopStart() {
    triggerAudio('1.wav'); 
}());

function triggerAudio(soundFileName) {
    (function loop() { // this function called repeatedly by callback
        setTimeout(function() { 
            // some code
            loop(); // callback
        }, randomTime); 
    }());
}
```

I've seen examples using `clearTimeout`, but I suspect this won't work in this case since I'm not really stopping a `setTimout`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question by changing `setTimeout(function() {` to `myVar = setTimeout(function() {` and using `clearTimeout`.

Here's the updated code:

```
(function loopStart() {
    triggerAudio('1.wav'); 
    setTimeout(function() {
        clearTimeout(myVar); // using clearTimeout here
}, 5000); 
}());

function triggerAudio(soundFileName) {
    (function loop() { // this function called repeatedly by callback
        myVar = setTimeout(function() { // added myVar = here
            // some code
            loop(); // callback
        }, randomTime); 
    }());
}
```